# Largest distance in an integer list

Tags: python, list

How to find the maximum distance between two same elements/integers of a list in python.
e.g. if a list is `[1,3,3,5,6,4,8,6,0,3,5]`
Output would be `8` (distance b/w 3's is maximum here)

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: Do you want to get the greatest number in a list?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a dictionary where for each value you save the indices.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

for i,el in enumerate(l):
    d[el].append(i)

max_dist = max(d[k][-1]-d[k][0] for k in d)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using numpy (slower than abc's solution):

```
import numpy as np

L = [1,3,3,5,6,4,8,6,0,3,5]
x, y = np.meshgrid(L, L)
w = np.where(x == y)
max_dist = np.max(w[1] - w[0])
```